# Kibana scripted fields using painless: How to find number of days passed using a preexisting index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, elasticsearch-painless, datetime-conversion

I have a bunch of data in Kibana that I need to clean up by using an scripted field with "painless" which is a version of Java. At the moment I have an preexisting index in my logs with a date in this format "2021-09-27T13:54:17.165Z" **I need to find how many days its been since that day until today whenever this search is ran, if its over or at 300 days it needs to return false if its lower true.**

I was trying this to get number of days its been:
`new Date().getTime() - doc['date'].value;`

I was on stack overflow I saw someone said that new Date().getTime() will give you todays date. But I think the issue is that the time **format** for new Date().getTime() returns time in the format of 1657151078131 but my index date is in "2021-09-27T13:54:17.165Z" **I am not sure how to convert it in order to find the displacement of less or more than 300 days.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated

#ELK #elasticsearch #kibana #elastic

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

You have an issue converting everything.
`new Date().getTime()` -> gives a Long
`"2021-09-27T13:54:17.165Z"` -> a string

## To Solve

You need to make move them to the same format.
Below I am converting the date in a `string` format to a `ZonedDateTime` then to a `long`.

```
new Date().getTime() - ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-09-27T13:54:17.165Z").toInstant().toEpochMilli() > 25920000000L;
```

That one way to go about it.
You can learn more about painless and time formats [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-datetime.html)